# jsf commandlink and commandbutton with rendered attribute does not fire actionlistener

Tags: java, jsf, scope, render, actionlistener

I am using primefaces to display some data on the page and when clicked on CLOB type data I want to open a popup(using primefaces dialog component) to display full data. The thing is when I put rendered atrribute to commandlink it won't fire the method at backing bean. It fires the method correctly if I don't use rendered atrribute. But it wont pass parameters correctly.

The backing bean is viewscoped. Could be about the bean's state is lost when I submit? If so, what is to be done to overcome this ?

Here is the source:

```
<p:dataTable id="dynamicDBReaderResultTable"
    widgetVar="wv_dynamicDBReaderResult" paginator="true" page="1"
    rows="10" value="#{controller.data}" var="record"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,100"
    emptyMessage="#{dtsmsgm['NoRecords']}"
    errorMessage="Error viewing data" rowIndexVar="rownumber" lazy="false"
    dynamic="true">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{rownumber+1}"
            style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.05em" />
    </p:column>
    <p:columns value="#{controller.columnNames}" var="columnName"
        columnIndexVar="columnIndex">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{columnName}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{record[columnIndex].toDisplayString()}" />

<p:commandLink id="showDataButton" value="..."
            actionListener="#{controller.prepareLargeData(rownumber,columnIndex)}"
            rendered="#{record[columnIndex].dataType eq '2005'}" //if this attribute is removed, it fires the action, but with both parameters as zero
            onsuccess="dlg.show()">
        </p:commandLink>



    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="largeDataDialog" header="Large Data Content"
    widgetVar="dlg" closeOnEscape="true" minHeight="150">
    <h:outputText id="largeData" value="#{controller.largeData}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dynamicDBReader")
@ViewScoped
public class DynamicDBReader extends AEntityBean<AEntity> {
private List<String> columnNames;
private List<DBData[]> tabularData;
private boolean showTable;
private DBData largeData;


public void prepareLargeData(int rowNumber, int columnIndex) {
    largeData = tabularData.get(rowNumber)[columnIndex];
}

@Override
public void init() {
    reInit();
}

private void reInit() {
    columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    tabularData = new ArrayList<DBData[]>();
    selectedRelease = getLastRelease();
    setShowTable(false);
}



public List<DBData[]> getData() {
    return tabularData;
}

public List<String> getColumnNames() {
    return columnNames;
}


/**
 * @param showTable
 *            the showTable to set
 */
public void setShowTable(boolean showTable) {
    this.showTable = showTable;
}

/**
 * @return the showTable
 */
public boolean isShowTable() {
    return showTable;
}

/**
 * @param largeData
 *            the largeData to set
 */
public void setLargeData(DBData largeData) {
    this.largeData = largeData;
}

/**
 * @return the largeData
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getLargeData() {
    if (largeData == null) {
        return "";
    }
    try {
        return largeData.toFullString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        String errorMessage = "Failed reading data";
        LogUtil.error(logger, errorMessage, ioe);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        String errorMessage = "Failed reading data";
        LogUtil.error(logger, errorMessage, sqle);
    }
    return "";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if the value of the variable `columIndex` has changed during the HTTP POST request of the form submit. That can in turn happen if the `#{controller.columnNames}` is dependent on a request based condition which was only correct during displaying the page with the table. You need to make sure that you preinitialize it in the (post)constructor of a view scoped bean and that the value is not initialized/manipulated in the getter method.

Comment: Well the table is dynamic. It gets data by passing entered query to db and displays results on the page. I display CLOB type data as <CLOB>...
I want to pass row number and column number as parameter to backing beans to get clob type data from tabular data to display on a popup. I do not update the table when clicked on "..." 
Column index is the client side index i obtain using columnIndexVar="columnIndex" atrribute of PrimeFaces's "columns" component. It is not stored in backing bean actually. @BalusC

Comment: This is in turn dependent on `#{controller.columnNames}` which is actually obtained from the backing bean.

Comment: But columNames does not change with clob data view requests. I just checked again to make sure. Well, i posted related part of my backing bean.

Also i tried something else. Instead of passing row and column indexes. I passed record[columIndex], the data object itself. But even when data is not null the object passed to backing bean is null  
@BalusC

Comment: Well, @BalusC you are right about columnIndex( and also rownumber), seems like when i pass them as parameters they are initialized with the value zero,so the parameter values are not initialized at build time.

I used <f:param> to get parameters created at build time. And they are passed to backing bean correctly when clicked.

But there still is the problem using rendered attribute. When i used the attribute, it will not fire the action prepareLargeData().Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: I am using columnIndex to see if commandlink should be rendered.I think that's what causing the problem. Dunno how can i achive conditional rendering  it without using columnIndex though. Stuck here

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I believe with columnIndexVar.  The number of columns in my datatable can change, but it only renders the correct number of columns when I call the method twice.  Data is loaded correctly the first time, though.  Any ideas?  Or should I open another question?